# Difference between "command" or specific module execution in Ansible

Tags: module, command, ansible

I'm starting with Ansible, and I found that there is a module called `command` which lets me execute any command in a remote node.

I saw a couple of example where initial setups are solved by using `command` instead of specific modules. For example, as far as I know, both of these do the same task:

```
- name: Install git using apt module
  apt:
    name: git
    state: present

- name: Install git using command
  command: apt-get install git
```

So, my question is: **is there any difference or any reason to use a module instead of command?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in short is that using a specific module will give you playbook's idempotence and provide better portability and readability.

What I mean by idempotence? When you run:

```
- name: Install git using apt module
  apt:
    name: git
    state: present
```

It will install git package only if it is not yet installed on the target system and after playbook run this task will be reported in green colour (`OK`) if git had been already installed.

2nd approach with the `command` module:

```
- name: Install git using command
  command: apt-get install git
```

Above command will always report status as `changed` (yellow colour) when in fact nothing changed (assuming git package had been already installed). There are ways to make tasks that use the `command` module idempotent as well but it costs you some more work.

Best practice is to always use a specific module before `command` in playbooks.

Ansible is all about describing and managing system state. When you run a playbook on a certain target system it can be very misleading to see a task reporting a `changed` state while in fact nothing has been changed.
Think declaratively about describing desired state, not about low level commands needed to get a system to this state.

Below article will also provide some explanation around differences and consequences of using `command` vs specific module:

[Ansible Best Practices: The Essentials](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials)

Answer (score 4):

There are probably numerous reasons but here are a few:

- Intrinsic idempotence (does not execute task every time without extra effort)
- Superior readability (much clearer what you are trying to do)
- More concise tasks (much fewer words to describe the task)
- Platform-agnostic execution (works on all OS instead of just one without extra effort)